# Many-To-Many relationship Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have had quite a few problems with my current entities mapping, so I wanted an opinion on what is the issue with it.

Let's say with have the following tables example with Doctrine, but also keep in mind that a **Group** can have many **Users**, and a *User* can be part of many **Groups**

```
User
--
id
name 

Group
--
id
title

User Groups
--
id
user_id
group_id
```

And this is my current approach:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SomeBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $user_id;
 // some other fields and functions here
}
```

Group

```
/**
     * Group
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="group", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="group_parent", columns={"parent_id"})})
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SomeBundle\Entity\Repository\GroupRepository")
     */
    class Group
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        private $categoryId;
    // some other functions and variables here
}
```

...and user_groups

```
/**
 * User_Groups
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_groups",
 *             indexes={
 *                      @ORM\Index(name="user_group_user", columns={"user_id"}),
 *                      @ORM\Index(name="user_group_group", columns={"group_id"})
 *                     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SomeBundle\Entity\Repository\UserGroupRepository")
 */
class UserGroup
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_group_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $userGroupId;

      /**
     * @var \SomeBundle\Entity\User
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id")
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SomeBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="userGroups")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users",
     * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="userId")})
     */

    private $user;

    /**
     * @var SomeBundle\Entity\Category
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SomeBundle\Entity\Group", inversedBy="groups")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="group_id")
     *
     */
    private $group;
/// etc
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: And what is the problem ?

Comment: First of all, I'd like to have an opinion in my annotations implementation, as I am not very experienced with that. Secondly, the error right now is: " `ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class SomeBundle\Entity\User could not be converted to string in ***/dev/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 120`"

Answer (score 2):

```
/** @Entity **/
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
     * @JoinTable(name="users_groups")
     **/
    private $groups;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->groups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}

/** @Entity **/
class Group
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups")
     **/
    private $users;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Your case is Many-to-Many, Bidirectional Association
[Doctrine association mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

Comment: Good point made by @wti The Doctrine will generate the table no need to create it.

Comment: Thanks alot for taking the time to provide me a very helpful example, Alexandru.
That will be first thing at the morning, as I do not have access to the code right now.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I have a `product` and a `mesureUnit` they relate many to many.
In your case you only need `user` and `group`. The `UserGroups` is generated automatically.
Many to many relationship are done as follows:

```
<?php
namespace TeamERP\StoresBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MesureUnit
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
 */
private $abreviation;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TeamERP\StoresBundle\Entity\ProductActivity", mappedBy="mesureUnit")
 */
private $pproductActivity;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TeamERP\StoresBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="mesureUnit")
 */
private $product;
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->pproductActivity = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->product = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Then the `produc` class could be like:

```
<?php
namespace TeamERP\StoresBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $code;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $date_received;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TeamERP\StoresBundle\Entity\ProductActivity", mappedBy="product")
 */
private $pproductActivity;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TeamERP\StoresBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $category;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TeamERP\StoresBundle\Entity\AJob", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $aJob;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TeamERP\StoresBundle\Entity\MesureUnit", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="MesureUnit2Product",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="mesure_unit_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)}
 * )
 */
private $mesureUnit;
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->pproductActivity = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->mesureUnit = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Yo do not need to create the table manually. It is generated by Doctrine.

Hope it helps

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this example.
I will definitely give it a go, first thing at the morning, as I do not have access to the code right now. Also, thanks alot for mentioning that Doctrine will create the join table automatically. Saves me some effort! :)

Comment: If you mean, test literaly the same example. The example does not have the setters and getters you have to add them. You should remove some variables especially relationships with other tables. This is part of a bigger project. If need more help just post and I will try to help.

Comment: I have got a question on this one:
So, lets say I'd like to save the **groups** that a **user** is member of, and at the moment I am doing this sth like this: 
`$userGroup = new UserGroup();` `$userGroup->setGroup($group);`  `$userGroup->setUser($user);`

But as long as there is no UserGroup entity, that fails.
Any ideas?

Comment: You do not interact wit the UserGroup table. basically any of them can have a collection of the other; a group can have many users and vice-verse. So you have to create for instance a user it an Arraycollection of groups inside and then you can save the user. check out this example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html Focus on the way they deal with the controller, the rest is not as important.